# iOS - pushViewController not working after conversion to xCode 9 / iOS 11

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I saw my iOS app isn't allowed to be downloaded from the app store with the most recent upgrade to iOS 11, so I'm trying to update it. I have it in Xcode 9, and I've managed to now get the app started on my iPhone 6. However, I can't seem to get it to display after my initial screen display.

For example, the initial display successfully displays and shows a button called "start". That should pop up another display when you press it, but it doesn't (although it is reaching the code which displays it).

Here's the code, in a class named "StartController.m", which should be calling up the display:

```
    NSLog(@"nav controller = %@", self.navigationController); 
    // push question controller onto the stack
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:questionController animated:YES];

    // the nav controller owns it now, we can release it
    [questionController release];
```

Debugging shows this code is successfully called when the button is pressed, but after the release of questionController, nothing happens. 
Here's the declaration of the questionController in StartController.h:

```
@interface StartController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>{ 
    QuestionController      *questionController;
```

And here's the declaration of the same in StartController.m:

```
@implementation StartController

@synthesize questionController, settingsController, nextLevelViewController, appState;
```

The initial view (with the "start" button) is successfully displayed with this code in the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method of the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // create the start controller 
    self.startController = [[StartController alloc] init];

    // transfer to it - not animated because it's the first view
    [navController pushViewController:startController animated:NO]; 

    // add the current nav controller view to the window view heirarchy 
    // [window addSubview:navController.view];

    [self.window setRootViewController:startController];

    // release becasause now the navController has it
    [startController release];

    // show the start controller 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

For reference, here's the declaration of the navController in the app delegate header:

```
@interface QuizAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow                *window;
    UINavigationController  *navController;
    StartController         *startController;   
}

@property (readonly) BOOL iPad; 
@property (nonatomic, retain)   IBOutlet    UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   StartController *startController;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   IBOutlet    UINavigationController *navController;
```

And here's the declaration in the implementation:

@implementation QuizAppDelegate

```
@synthesize window;
@synthesize startController;
@synthesize navController;
```

I tried not to post too much code for fear of obscuring the problem, but I'll add it if requested. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: You should be setting `navController` as the root view controller of the window, not `startController`

Comment: Great, thanks! Can you post as an answer, I'll accept.